# Should I use "were" or "be" in this subjunctive sentence?

Tags: subjunctives

> Had the affordable automated machines **were** available, the safety could have been improved at a minimal cost.

OR

> Had the affordable automated machines **be** available, the safety could have been improved at a minimal cost.

Which of the above two sentences is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are close, but neither is correct.

When you talk about a hypothetical thing in the past, you have to [backshift](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/sentence/reported-speech-backshift.htm) the tenses. Let's start with a simple statement: at some time in the past, these machines were available:

> Affordable automated machines **were** available...

If we know that they were not available in the past, and we ask a hypothetical question about what would have happened if this were not true, we backshift simple past to past perfect:

> If affordable automated machines **had been** available...

Now we apply a small stylistic adjustment, removing the **if** and making the clause conditional by moving **had** to the beginning:

> **Had** affordable automated machines **been** available...

You can read more about this alternative form of conditional sentence [here](http://www.eslcafe.com/grammar/conditional_sentences09.html).

Note that you don't need the definite article **the** before **affordable** and **safety**.